# Storing generic data in the form of void pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers, void-pointers

> I am trying to use void pointer to store generic data in C language

This is the structure to store generic data type

```
 struct Node{
        int id;  // Id of the node 
        void *data; // Variable Which stores data
    };
```

I am storing data through this method

```
int graph_setnode_data(graph_t *graph,int id,void *data){
    struct Node *node = getnode(graph,id);
    if(node != NULL){
        node->data = data;
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

And accessing data through

```
void* graph_getnode_data(graph_t *graph,int id){
    struct Node *node = getnode(graph,id);
    if(node != NULL){
        return node;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

And here is how I am using these methods

```
struct Person{
    char *name;
    int age;
};
int main(){
    struct Person *person = malloc(sizeof(struct Person));
    person->name = "Goutam";
    person->age = 21;

    graph_t *graph = graph_init(2);
    graph_createpath(graph,0,1);
    graph_createpath(graph,1,0);
    graph_setnode_data(graph,0,(void *)person);
    struct Person *data =(struct Person *) graph_getnode_data(graph,0);
    printf("%d\n",data->age);
    graph_destroy(graph);
    return 0;
}
```

But I am getting the output:

`38162448`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning the node, not the data stored in your node:

```
void* graph_getnode_data(graph_t *graph,int id){
    struct Node *node = getnode(graph,id);
    if(node != NULL){
        return node->data; // <---- This should fix the bug.
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Hey,Thanks you spotted it out